# Convert DateTime to DateTime that works with SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to add some dates to some asp.net membership fields (LastLoginDate, LastPasswordChangedDate, etc)

so what I did was

```
DateTime sendDate = new DateTime(1754, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0);
```

then I tired to use linq to sql and add them.

It comes back with an exception

```
"SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."
```

I am not sure how to convert it into something that will be let in.

```
DateTime dateFields = new DateTime(1800, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0);
aspnet_Membership membership = new aspnet_Membership();
                membership.ApplicationId = applicationId;
                membership.UserId = userId;
                membership.Password = password;
                membership.PasswordFormat = passwordFormat;
                membership.PasswordSalt = base64Salt;
                membership.MobilePIN = null;
                membership.Email = email;
                membership.LoweredEmail = email.ToLower();
                membership.PasswordQuestion = null;
                membership.PasswordAnswer = null;
                membership.IsApproved = isApproved;
                membership.IsLockedOut = false;
                membership.CreateDate = dateCreated;
                membership.LastLoginDate = dateFields;
                membership.LastPasswordChangedDate = dateFields;
                membership.LastLoginDate = dateFields;
                membership.FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart = dateFields;
                membership.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = 0;
                membership.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart = dateFields;
                membership.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = 0;
                membership.Comment = null;


                // from asp.net mvc unleashed book.
                GenericRepository.Create<aspnet_Membership>(membership);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you get "dateCreated" from in the c#? What value is it?

And you are not setting "LastLockoutDate"... you actually have "LastLoginDate" twice. What values are being set for LastLockoutDate?

It looks like "dateFields" is correct for datetime in SQL Server terms (which is used by [aspnet_Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx)), perhaps the error comes from elsewhere...

Comment: Thanks I was sure I had all the right fields but theirs just too many "La" ones that I keep on thinking I had them all. Thats what I missing. "LastLockOutDate".

I with you could like pass the stuff in as a param or something in linq to sql then having to do it by properties. It gets confusing when you have to add tons of properties with similar names.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there's just one more DateTime field that you're not yet filling?? In that case, it would default to 01/01/0001 and that's outside the `DATETIME` range for SQL Server.

If you're on SQL Server 2008, you could avoid this be using the `DATETIME2` type - this has a valid date range of 01/01/0001 through 12/31/9999

Marc

Comment: I tried putting Date.Now still the same thing too. Can someone see if I am missing one or what is going on?

Comment: **SQL Server 2008** - not VS2008 ! Also, do you possibly create an associated object that might contain DateTime fields?

Comment: Lol my bad I meant Sever 2005

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you're sending it in the wrong order.

What does your SQL clause look like? If you're just setting a SqlParameter (as you should be) life should be quite okay, assuming the parameters of the DateTime are set correctly.

Comment: Well that's weird.

I'd see if you can figure out what SQL query the MemberhipProvider is actually executing. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

I don't know the DateTime constructor off the top of my head either, so make sure you're passing the right parameters to it; perhaps it is not making what you think it's making.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have the right parameters and not sure what the MembershipProvider has to do with it. I am not using any membership methods. This is like using my own query to insert something into a table that just happens to be a membership table.

Comment: Okay; I'm not familiar with what 'GenericRepository' is. I'd try writing the query manually with SqlCommand and SqlParameters, and seeing if you get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that you allow NULL for the DateTime columns.
2. Also check the locales/date formats on the SQL
   server. It may just expect day,
   month or year in a different order (e.g. m/d/y vs dd/mm/yyy)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function to convert with.

```
public static string GetDateTimeSQLString(DateTime SomeTime)
{
    //yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
    string SqlTime = SomeTime.Year.ToString() + "-" + SomeTime.Month.ToString() + "-" + SomeTime.Day.ToString() + " " + SomeTime.Hour.ToString() + ":" + SomeTime.Minute + ":" + SomeTime.Second.ToString();
    return SqlTime;
}
```